# Angular 7 HttpHeaders are empty

Tags: angular, typescript, http, immutability

I understand that HttpHeaders are immutable. I've tried several different ways to initialize them, or append to them, but when I log them it always shows they are empty.

I've tried initializing them with all values:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
```

And I've tried setting:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`);
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

And I've tried appending:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.accessToken}`);
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

But all result in empty headers and the API says it was unable to find any authorization token.

#### Console output:

[image: Console output of http headers]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you setting them in the http call?

Comment: Here's how I'm setting it up, but I can't imagine this explaining why they are empty when I log them (before making this call) `return this.http.post<ZTask>('/api/ztask', ztask, { headers: headers })`

Comment: I see what you mean.  If you do `headers.keys().forEach(x => { console.log(headers.get(x)) })` you can see they are there.  Hopefully someone who's kept up on Angular can help!

Comment: `headers.getAll('Authorization')` if you are logging it, but a better place to check will be Network tab in DevTools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably due to [lazy parsing](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders), you have to do a `get` to access values. Not implemented as a key -  value pair.

> HttpHeaders class represents the header configuration options for an
>   HTTP request. Instances should be assumed immutable with lazy parsing.

Do `console.log(headers.getAll('Authorization'))`

But, to make sure headers are sent, a better place to check will be **Network tab** in DevTools.

Comment: This is exactly why it wasn't logging. Thanks.